# Python: Best way to translate constants?

Tags: python, constants

Background:
I am adding a new function to an existing class which needs to return a list of names of constants.

Lets say I have a number of constants in a class

```
JOHN = 1
SMITH = 4
BEN = 8
...
```

And I have web service function which returns a list constant values, instead of returning `[1,4,8]` I would like to return more meaningful data such as `['JOHN', 'SMITH', 'BEN']`

What is the efficient way to do it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Where is this list of constants?  On the web server?  How is it returning those constants, serverside, or via an HTTP request?

Comment: try [flufl.enum](http://packages.python.org/flufl.enum/)

Comment: A `dict` might be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map()` along with a mapping dictionary.

```
arg_map = {1 : 'JOHN', 4 : 'SMITH', 8 : 'BEN'}
translated_result = map(arg_map.get, result_list)
```

As mentioned in the comments, a list comprehension would also work here.  Note you could make this a generator by replacing the square brackets with parens.

```
arg_map = {1 : 'JOHN', 4 : 'SMITH', 8 : 'BEN'}
translated_result = [arg_map.get(val, '%s NOT MAPPED' % str(val)) for val in result_list]
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension instead of `map` would make for more idiomatic python code, but otherwise that's the best way to go.

Comment: I was expecting some magic function/code I didn't know, looks like I need to use a dictionary then, since all the constants are already defined, I might have to do {'JOHN':JOHN, 'BEN':BEN}

Comment: It would probably be better to refactor in to a dictionary so things are only defined once.  If you can't do that though, sure, what you say will work fine (though the key needs to be the value to want to map from, not the one you want to map to).

Comment: The list comprehension is "slightly" overcomplicated ;) `[arg_map[x] for x in args]` would be the simplest solution and would throw an exception if an invalid int is provided (better than adding a "Not mapped" string to the results imo, but depends on the problem)

Comment: @JamesLin: you might not have to build a separate object and explicitly list them.  If the values can be recognized from their names, then something like `d = {k: getattr(obj, k) for k in dir(obj) if not k.startswith("__")}` would extract the values into a dict without specifying them.  [You could do the reverse too.]

Comment: @Voo, yup, but I wanted to show how you could give a default value rather than an exception too.

Comment: @JamesLin Lin, then don't.  Just refactor everything in to one place.  If you have other things that depend on the old values, dynamically generate them at runtime from the single set of master data.  You could do it by starting with the hardcoded consts as in DSM's example, or go the other way and insert the dict you create (or it's key/value switched mirror) in to the object's `__dict__`.

Comment: hmmm I might just do a dict map for now, the class is too important to change for now and I need to get this function done rather soon.